# Convert css position to jquery smooth sliding

Tags: jquery, css

I currently have a `<div>` that maintains its position at the top of the left had side of the page, when the page moves up or down. This works fine but isn't very smooth.

I'm looking to re-factor the code below to make this a smooth scroll. Currently when the trigger happens it just sets the CSS `top` property - which makes it "jittery". I'm a little unsure how to make this a smooth scroll motion opposed to setting the css top value to its exact location

```
        //scrolling menu
    if($("#selectedOptions").length > 0){   //if the element exists
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var div = $("#selectedOptions");        // the div that slides
            if(div) {                               
                var pos = div.parent().position().top;  //position of the top of the wrapper
                var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop();  //current window postion

                //top of moving div not to go further than
                var bottom = $("#sizeAndQuantHeader").position().top; //where the div shouldn't go past 

                //de-bug
                //console.log("pos: " + pos + " - winpos" + windowPos + ", heih: " + divHieght + " doc he: " + $(document).height() + " bott" + bottom);

                //if between the range then display at new postion
                if (windowPos > pos && (windowPos < bottom)) {
                    div.css("top", windowPos-pos);
                    //must be higher than its current position so set to 0
                 } else if (windowPos < pos && windowPos < bottom) {
                     div.css("top", 0);
                } 
            }
        });
    }
```

Any help or tips on how to make a `<div>` scroll smoothly down a page would be much appreciated.

**Update

Unfortunately, i have elements that already scroll around different page areas:

```
var _scrollTo = function(div){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: div.offset().top},
        'slow');
};
```

Now when the function above is called i think it triggers the call:

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){animate div...
```

and delays the scrolling of the newly animated div. I cant't use call back either as it's re-used else where. I may be missing something here so i've resorted back to no animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key would be changing this code here:

```
if (windowPos > pos && (windowPos < bottom)) {
    div.css("top", windowPos-pos);
    //must be higher than its current position so set to 0
} else if (windowPos < pos && windowPos < bottom) {
    div.css("top", 0);
}
```

To

```
if (windowPos > pos && (windowPos < bottom)) {
    div.animate({top: windowPos-pos}, 100);
    //must be higher than its current position so set to 0
} else if (windowPos < pos && windowPos < bottom) {
    div.animate({top: "0"}, 100);
}
```

[jQuery's `animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) is really easy to use/manipulate.

Comment: @dezza Glad to have helped (:

Comment: I can't discredit the original answer but beware of full page animations detrimental to this animation. See **update

Answer (score 3):

Use Animate to make it smooth.

```
div.animate({ top: windowPos-pos }, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

add css to div (#selectedOptions)

```
transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
```

It will go smooth automatically.